# OG meta tags and Facebook 'Send' button fail

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm pretty sure the meta tags and Send button code are fine.  I'll show that code below anyways but I'm pretty sure the code is correct.

Here's what I think my problem stems from:

1) I have a FB 'Send' button on a page in my site called **landing_page.php**

2) I therefore specify

```
     <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.oursite.com/landing_page.php"/>
```

for the 'url' meta tag for the page.

3) When I go to https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug -- and then type in
   my page URL of http://www.oursite.com/landing_page.php --- I get an error msg.:

***Error Parsing URL:   Error parsing input URL, no data was scraped.***

So my question is -- must I put the Send button ONLY on the index.php page?

I thought I could put the Send button on ANY page as long as I put the meta tags
and Send button code on that page.   But the Facebook debugger complains

***Error Parsing URL:   Error parsing input URL, no data was scraped.***

if I put the Send button and associated code on 'anypage.php' and try to use it --
the Send box that appears picks up NONE of my OG meta tags (see below)  and the
Facebook debugger cannot 'scrape' an arbitrary page in my site.

**Must I put the Send button ONLY on the index.php page?**
Or what do I need to change so the Send button on landing_page.php works and shows my OG meta tag settings??

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
 <html
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
   xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"
   xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">

 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

 <head>
 <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.oursite.com/landing_page.php"/>
 <meta property="og:title" content="Wow cool title!"/>
 <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.oursite.com/images/logo.png"/>
 <meta property="og:description" content="Hey -- SUPER-COOL!!"/>
  etc.


  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="fb-root"></div> 
        <script>
        (function(d, s, id) 
        { 
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0]; 
            if (d.getElementById(id)) return; 
            js = d.createElement(s); 
            js.id = id;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs); 
        }
        (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
       </script>

      <div class="fb-send" data-href="http://www.oursite.com"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add appid as well to scrap your page

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="${fb_app_id}"/>
```

Asuming that u have added this tag in the landing_page.php

You can use this send button any where in the website

Comment: I cannot get an app id.  We HAD an app id.  But we created it, got distracted by other stuff for 2 weeks, and when we came back to the part of our code that needed the app id, Facebook told us 'You no longer have permission to...' or somesuch and after investigating that issue -- our CTO told us 'If Facebook can arbitrarily de-activate an app id -- BEFORE WE EVER USED IT -- then we will not write any code that requires the app id with Facebook -- they are too whimsical with developers that they do this."  Our team agreed, since we never wrote even 1 line of code using our new app id.

Comment: I mean did u created it from your own fb account

Comment: do one thing in place of app id just add your fb id   <meta property="fb:admins" content="${your_fb_id}"/>

Comment: The CTO said 'if Facebook requires a personal Facebook user's account to create an app_id we cannot use it as the employee or officer of the company might move on to a new employer at some point.'  So it was the lead developer's facebook account that was used to get the App Id but no way will our leadership allow the project to write code that relies on a very fragile poorly thought out developer connection.

Comment: whereabouts can we find an 'your_fb_id'  ??  Not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: See we need an account_id only to create a FB account and then we always have a option to change and remove admins and even that Id used to create the App.

Comment: Do you have a facebook account

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10207/discussion-between-charsee-and-wantthebest)

Answer (score 0):

you need to put the meta tags in http://www.oursite.com/landing_page.php also because the fb not found any meta tags on the mentioned url

Also check the Fetched URL in the debugger tool. That will show what exactly they found from your url

Comment: The meta tags in my post above ARE in fact inside the file www.oursite.com/landing_page.php.   You have good advice to be sure.  But we've already done it.  The debugger says  "Error parsing input URL, no data was scraped."  There's no option to check the Fetched URL -- all we see after clicking 'Debug' is the 'Error parsing.......' error message.

Comment: but when we goto Scraped URL then it shows that it is not having any meta tags.